# Обращение к телеграмм боту на пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, api, telebot

Существует телеграмм бот. Задача написать скрипт ,который сможет отправлять запрос боту и получать ответы .Нужно чтобы скрипт работал без установленного на компе телеграмма. Язык - Python 3 . Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли это , какие библиотеки использовать. (использовать в скрипте логин/парроль пользователя нельзя)

Comment: за что дизлайки? можете обьяснить что не так

Comment: Думаю, минусуют потому, что вопрос сформулирован так, что непонятна его суть. Бот запущен в отдельном процессе, и скрипт отдельный процесс? Т.е. вам нужно организовать взаимодействие между двумя питон процессами? В этом суть вопроса? Или вам из скрипта нужно запустить процесс бота с параметрами? По взаимодействию между процессами на ruSO уже есть ответы. В общем нужно объяснить, что значить"обращаться и получать ответы"

Comment: нужно, чтобы любой пк запустив скрип смог получить доступ к боту

Comment: ну ладно не хотите отвечать так, будет конкурс

Comment: Могу сказать за себя - я не получил ответы на свои вопросы и не могу помочь, так как не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: я переформулировал вопрос, посомтрите пожалуйста, если не ответят будет конкурс 100%

Comment: Нужно чтобы через программу/скрипт можно было взаимодействовать с телеграмм аккаунта с другим ботом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По правде говоря, непонятно для чего нужен такой подход разработки бота, и скорее действительно РАБОЧЕЕ решение создать невозможно, но тем не менее можно реализовать что-то подобное, но не настолько как вы задумали.

По сути можно таки реализовать примерно, то что вы хотите костылем (я бы даже назвал костылищем) - создать публичную группу, настроить права боту, получить идентификатор `supergroup`, и удалить всех юзеров из группы, тогда да - в таком случае действительно не нужен ни один аккаунт в Telegram, чтобы отправить куда-то сообщение, но по сути клиента для взаимодействия с ботом нет, и напрашивается вопрос - зачем вам монолог? Поэтому правильным и единственным решением нужен хотя бы один аккаунт, а точнее `chat_id` (логин и пароль никуда ботом не передаются и не используются, только идентификаторы чата).

API Telegram, как и все остальные - это клиент-серверное решение. То есть клиент что-то отравляет серверу, после этого сервер выдает результат и потом информация отдается клиенту. Поэтому можно предположить, что без клиента подобная задача в принципе невозможна.

Давайте заглянем в официальную документацию элементарно к самому простому методу для отправки простых сообщений [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage). Можно увидеть, что id пользователя (то есть клиента) есть обязательным при отправке сообщения

[image]

Исходя из этого - нужен хотя бы один аккаунт в Telegram-e для взаимодействия с ботом. Если нужно отправить в группу/канал - используются отрицательные идентификаторы, например `-10011234567890` НО! Как вы должны знать, управление ботом происходит через API, то есть используется `json`-объекты. Исходя из этого - не обязательно использовать готовые библиотеки для разработки ботов, по сути это обертки над методами Telegram, все они построены на одном и том же принципе, который я описал выше - отправка на сервер данных клиентом, и их получение. Как говорится - за нас уже все сделали, упростив нам жизнь, простым смертным:). Но если вы сильны духом, вам преграды не страшны, и хотите пойти тяжелым путем, то есть описать все желаемые для вас методы (в этом нет особого смысла, потому что их за нас уже написали) поэтому затронем только некоторые методы для реализации примера.

Боты могут работать 2 разными способами - один через `getUpdates`, а второй через `webhook`. Вы можете сами погуглить про `long_polling` и `webhook` для ботов, так как это доступно будет описано по первой же ссылке в гугле, я в это вдаваться не буду, возьму для простоты `getUpdates`.

Чтобы отправить в чат/группу сообщение, нужно отправить `POST`-запрос на сервер Telegram. Реализуем это через простой в использовании `requests`

Простой пример отправки сообщения:

```
import requests

token = 'ваш токен'
data = {'chat_id': 'Ваш id', 'text': 'Test message'}
r = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?', data=data)
print(r.json())
# и далее ваше взаимодействие с `json`-объектом
```

Простой пример получения сообщения, которые отправлял пользователь боту:

```
import requests

token = 'ваш токен'
# data_offset = {'offset': 1234567801}
r = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates')  #, data=data_offset)
print(r.json())
```

`data_offset` нужен для того, чтобы подтвердить на сервере Telegram, что вы ответили на это сообщение. Но чтобы ответ оказался подтвержденным - нужно инкрементировать `offset` на единицу больше, то есть отправить `data_offset = {'offset': 1234567802}`

Это в двух словах, как это работает. Чтобы это все реализовать - вам понадобится не один, и даже два дня.

Так что совет - переконструируйте архитектуру вашей задачи. У меня все:)

Comment: решение интересное(где до конкурса были такие люди?((( ) , но все таки мне нужно не только выполнение команд но и получение ответов. Попытаюсь поподробнее обьяснить смысл, существует некоторая программа, она работает нормально на пк пользователя но при этом иногда ей нужно спросить что-то у сервера, сервером является тг бот. Очень не хочется требовать у пользователя писать данные своего аккаунта в телеграмме, поэтому пытаюсь найти другое решение.

Comment: @root_of_the_live, хм, так вам по идее, чтоб получить данные с сервера - не нужен логин и пароль. Все что вам нужно, это только знать токен, и прочитать `getUpdates` как я привел в ответе. Если этот бот конечно, работает не на вебхуках.